# "Happy birthday" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, saludos

Say you have a Spanish friend and today is his/her birthday. How can you say "happy birthday" in an appropriate way?

> Muchas felicidades

Is my guess but it probably depends on the context and on how much confidence you have with the person.

Also: is there any other sentence you can say after that? Somethink like "I hope you have a great day".

I would imagine something like

> Que cumplas muchos más

Comment: Both are correct. "Feliz Cumpleaños! Muchas Felicidades". A hug, and then "Que cumplas muchos más".  You can also say "Ojalá que sean más" (Hopefully they will be more).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Herman , this makes much sense! Do you think the hug is always appropriate? I guess it may depend on countries and/or confidence.

Comment: If it is a friend, I would say yes, the hug is appropriate. But this goes beyond the scope of "Spanish Language"; of course :)

Comment: @Gorpik this may lead to a Spanish _Body_ Language site on Stack Exchange :D

Comment: Well. I can say with confidence that every language has a huge component of "Body Language". A birthday hug is customary among everybody regardless familiarity, class or whatever factor, at least I can say that for Chile and Spain. Is completely normal that, say, the CEO comes and give a handshake and a hug to an employee for her birthday.

Comment: @Herman you can probably make a good answer out of your comments!

Comment: I don't want to be the party pooper, but some people have complained sometimes about questions related with Spanish-speaking countries culture, rather than Spanish language. I am not against those questions, so I won't do the complaining, anyway. I might, nevertheless, go to Meta to check if the issue has been discussed before.

Comment: @Gorpik thanks for the comment. As you know, I am trying to ask questions that can get us more users and visits. I thought this one could be a good one, so I tried to phrase it in a more complex way than a mere "how do you say Happy birthday in Spanish?" (that would have been correctly closed as "off-topic for asking translations"). The comments have led to this cultural aspect, but I still think the main point here is as basic as knowing how can this basic sentence be said. Having answers with distinctions among countries and contexts will make the whole thing more interesting, of course!

Comment: @Gorpik and of course I will be more than open to reset the way I am asking questions so that they are more useful for the community.

Comment: To be honest, I think these cultural aspects are a good addition to the site if they are kept to a reasonable level. Languages are not isolated from their surrounding culture. Definitely, I'm going to Meta to discuss the issue and try to get a good consensus.

Comment: Well, the proposed site FAQ already covers this. It reads: "[Don't ask] questions of culture that don't directly relate to the Spanish language". Since this is related to language usage, I take back my previous comments.

Comment: @Gorpik thanks! But please, do not remove comments [yet], since it is good information that others may want to complete.

Comment: Este realmente es un tema que me avergüenza jajaja, te dejo un vídeo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBOS3mKpyzs

Comment: @fedorqui Oh, no, I never remove comments. What I said, I said, even if I later stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know in Spain but in Latin America we say

> **Feliz cumpleaños** = Happy birthday
>
> **Feliz cumpleaños [nombre]** = Happy birthday [name]
>
> **Feliz cumpleaños [nombre de cariño]** = Happy birthday [special name] (For close friends)

To all these expressions you can add many phrases where you express your enthusiasm or your care

> **Feliz cumpleaños, muchas felicidades**
>
> **Feliz cumpleaños, que lo pases [muy feliz / muy bien / excelente]**
>
> **Feliz cumpleaños, muchas felicidades, que lo pases [muy feliz / muy 
>   bien / excelente]**
>
> **¡Feliz cumpleaños y que cumplas muchos más!***
>
> **¡Feliz cumpleaños, muchas felicidades y [muchos] éxitos!**

Usually we start with **feliz cumpleaños** and then we add something else. Sometimes it depends on the relationship with the other person and that could be followed with a half hug or a full hug or just a handshake

At work, strictly in Latin America some people develop a strong relationship with their bosses, so they can give a half hug, it means you approach to the other and your left hand on the back of the other person and your right hand on his right arm (I'm just trying to give an example not a rule). Women in Latin America are more emotional and they can give a full hug with their female bosses or co-workers but with males are more formal. Only if that girl is your partner in crime, she will give you a full hug.

Remember it depends on how close is your relationship with the other person.

In North America, at work, they tend to say happy birthday face to face without contact (mostly but not a rule) and that's it. They follow their lives.

Comment: Spain is basically the same, though I hear *que lo pases bien* more than *feliz* (or with the younger crowd, *de puta madre*)

Comment: @guifa Or not so younger. I've heard muliple times from people  having 40~50

Answer (score 2):

***Payaso Plin Plin:***

```
Al payaso Plin Plin
se le pinchó la nariz
y con un estornudo
hizo fuerte ¡Achís!
```

- ***Fuente:*** [*Payaso Plin Plin letra*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YSbBoMg8bk)

---

***Cumpleaños feliz:***

```
¡Que los cumplas Feliz!
¡Que los cumplas Feliz!
¡Que los cumplas [*name here*]!
¡Que los cumplas Feliz!
```

- ***Fuente:*** [*El payaso Plin Plin y el Feliz cumpleaños son la misma canción*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBOS3mKpyzs)

---

***Feliz en tu día***

```
¡Feliz, feliz en tu día!
¡Ojalá que te pise un tranvía!
¡Que comas batata podrida!
¡Y que cumplas para atrás!
```

- ***Fuente:*** [*El cumple de Pepe*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FolKzCgX0X4)

---

**Original:** Feliz en tu día

```
Feliz, feliz en tu día 
Amiguito que Dios te bendiga 
Que reine la paz en tu día 
Y que cumplas muchos más
```

- ***Fuente:*** [*Feliz en tu día*](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1814298)

---

Answer (score 1):

I will make an answer out of the commentaries I made:

Both are correct. "**Feliz Cumpleaños! Muchas Felicidades**". A hug, and then "**Que cumplas muchos más**". You can also say "**Ojalá que sean más**" (Hopefully they will be more).

A birthday hug is customary among everybody regardless familiarity, class or whatever factor. At least I can say that for Chile and Spain. Is completely normal that, say, the CEO comes and give a handshake and a hug to an employee for her birthday.

With respect to some comments I've read. Cultural aspects DO matter in the study of any language. You just can't learn a language without getting involved in the culture it is spoken within. Is like trying to learn japanese without understanding the strict social norms they have (You need to conjugate verbs based on your relative social standing of your listeners).